# CocoaPods could not find compatible versions for pod "firebase_auth": In Podfile

Tags: ios, firebase, flutter, cocoapods

I'm trying to run `pod install` on my terminal but i'm getting this error below.

**The error:**

```
[!] CocoaPods could not find compatible versions for pod "firebase_auth":
  In Podfile:
    firebase_auth (from `.symlinks/plugins/firebase_auth/ios`)

Specs satisfying the `firebase_auth (from `.symlinks/plugins/firebase_auth/ios`)` dependency were found, but they required a higher minimum deployment target.
```

**My pubspec.yaml:**

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter

  progress_dialog: ^1.2.4
  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2
  firebase_auth: ^3.1.3
  firebase_core: ^1.7.0
  firebase_database: ^8.0.0
  flutter_native_splash: ^1.2.4
  url_launcher: ^6.0.12
```

My PodFile:

```
# Uncomment this line to define a global platform for your project
# platform :ios, '9.0'

# CocoaPods analytics sends network stats synchronously affecting flutter build latency.
ENV['COCOAPODS_DISABLE_STATS'] = 'true'

project 'Runner', {
  'Debug' => :debug,
  'Profile' => :release,
  'Release' => :release,
}

def flutter_root
  generated_xcode_build_settings_path = File.expand_path(File.join('..', 'Flutter', 'Generated.xcconfig'), __FILE__)
  unless File.exist?(generated_xcode_build_settings_path)
    raise "#{generated_xcode_build_settings_path} must exist. If you're running pod install manually, make sure flutter pub get is executed first"
  end

  File.foreach(generated_xcode_build_settings_path) do |line|
    matches = line.match(/FLUTTER_ROOT\=(.*)/)
    return matches[1].strip if matches
  end
  raise "FLUTTER_ROOT not found in #{generated_xcode_build_settings_path}. Try deleting Generated.xcconfig, then run flutter pub get"
end

require File.expand_path(File.join('packages', 'flutter_tools', 'bin', 'podhelper'), flutter_root)

flutter_ios_podfile_setup

target 'Runner' do
  use_frameworks!
  use_modular_headers!

  flutter_install_all_ios_pods File.dirname(File.realpath(__FILE__))
end

post_install do |installer|
  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
    flutter_additional_ios_build_settings(target)
  end
end
```

Comment: `flutter clean` then `flutter pub get` then delete your Podfile.lock and try again

Comment: @Er1 i don't have one

Comment: Have you checked which min. deployment target you need https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/installation/ios#ios-supported-versions Find out how to change it here: https://flutter.dev/docs/deployment/ios

Comment: Try `pod update` instead.

Comment: @PaulBeusterien same error

Comment: Try adding `platform :ios, '10.0'`

Comment: @PaulBeusterien yes, that was the problem, if you want post an answer :-)

Comment: Great! Answer added.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add `platform :ios, '10.0'` to the Podfile.

The latest versions of Firebase require at least iOS 10.